# How do I find the equations of the planes containing the faces of this tetrahedron?

Tags: plane-geometry

The points are $(0,0,2), (0,2,0), (0,0,0),$ and $(4,2,0)$. I know the y and z components of the equation will just be the intercepts but I'm not sure how to incorporate the $(4,2,0)$ point. I need the equations to calculate the flux using the divergence theorem.

Comment: The "equation of a tetrahedron" would just be the four equations of the four planes that are its four faces.

Comment: A tetrahedron has 4 vertices. $(4,2,0)$ is just one of them.